# why I cannot build QEMU for RISC-V?

Tags: simulator

I tried to build QEMU for RISC-V ISA simulator.

However, after I downloaded it and type the following:

```
$ ./configure --target-list=riscv-softmmu
```

It gave me this:

> ERROR: Unknown target name 'riscv-softmmu'

Can anyone shed some lights on it?

I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue with the configure command in your question is that the target name is invalid. The available RISC-V configure targets are

- riscv64-softmmu
- riscv32-softmmu
- riscv64-linux-user *(linux only)*
- riscv32-linux-user *(linux only)*

Also, the RISC-V port was accepted into QEMU 2.12, so you need to be using the most recent version. There are more details on SiFive's blog:

- https://www.sifive.com/blog/2018/04/25/risc-v-qemu-part-2-the-risc-v-qemu-port-is-upstream/

If you want to try the latest version of the RISC-V QEMU port, you can clone and build the riscv-qemu GitHub repository:

### Linux

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu.git
cd riscv-qemu
./configure --target-list=\
riscv64-softmmu,riscv32-softmmu,\
riscv64-linux-user,riscv32-linux-user
```

### macOS

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu.git
cd riscv-qemu
./configure --target-list=\
riscv64-softmmu,riscv32-softmmu
```

The RISC-V QEMU Port Wiki contains a collection of information on the port include links to Operating System images for RISC-V QEMU:

- https://github.com/riscv/riscv-qemu/wiki